# How to make QCombobox expandable for hierarchical items? (PyQT5)

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a some dictionary variables such as :

```
{"Courses" : ["Math" , "Science" , "English"]} , 
{"Cars" : ["Ford" , "BMW" , "Mercedes"]} , etc.
```

When I get the selected value of the QCombobox, I lose the key to which it applies!

Comment: can you provide a minimal working example?

Comment: http://codepad.org/MljIT789

How do I get keys ("Courses", "Cars") when choosing items?

Comment: Thanks for the example, I added an aswer, hope it solves your problem. The whole code is here: http://codepad.org/sraoTV7Y

Comment: when I transfer the code to my project I have an error: AttributeError: 'MovingDTranslator' object has no attribute 'sender'

Comment: The example I provided works, so I think you screw up something when you integrate it to your project.

Comment: what happens if your class inherits 'QtWidgets.QWidget' instead of 'object'? Does that solve your problem?

Comment: I made a mistake, it's worked)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this is adding a helper function to your class, that prints the key for you:

```
    def getKey(self):
        current = self.sender()
        for key, val in self.combo.items():
            if val == current:
                print(key, val.currentText())
```

Then I connected this function to your comboboxes:

```
    for k in lst:
        self.combo[k] = QComboBox()
        self.combo[k].addItems(lst[k])
        self.combo[k].currentIndexChanged.connect(self.getKey)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.combo[k])
```